# How to put two divs side by side in email template for Oulook 2013

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I want to put text and a image (20*20) together in a email template . for this i am two divs with float:left . everything is working fine except on outlook 2013.

in outlook 2nd div is going below to 1st divs. hence image is coming below to text.

if i removed divs then image and text are not in inline together.

please help me to solve this small issue.

Answer (score 2):

[**TL;DR: Use `<table>s` instead of `<div>`s.**](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/guidelines/) Emails are a different from web pages in this regard. Furthermore, desktop Outlook uses Microsoft Word to render emails, which is pretty terrible :)

Instead of using two `<div>`s, try something like this:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td width="580">Text</td>
        <td width="20">Image</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```